# Swift iOS MapKit Is there a way to pinch zoom in as far as you want?

Tags: swift, ios8, mapkit, zooming

I am building an app that draws graphic overlays over the map data. There will be times where the user will want to zoom in to levels far past what imagery tiles are available. This would be desired in cases where you want to place CG elements accurately in close proximity to each other. For that quick operation, you would forfeit the ability to view the map imagery.

So, is there a way to zoom further than the normal maximum zoom?

Or, ideally, I would like it to be that you could continue zooming in and the last available tile/resolution would continue to expand (past the default maximum). The fact that the resolution would get worse as you zoomed - would be secondary in those situations.

...if anyone knows a way to achieve the first request, but not the latter; would you also know how to change the default map background wallpaper (or is there a function I can populate that fires at the transition to - loss of imagery)?